# Local maximum implies that the second partial derivative is non positive

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function in $R^n$. Show that if it has a local maximum at a point $x_0$, then $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j^2}\leq0$ for each $j\in\{ 1,2,3...,n \}$

My attempt:
I fix one direction. And can show that the first partial will be zero by following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632947/proof-that-the-derivative-of-an-extremum-is-0) proof.
But then how would I extend it to the second partial derivative. Or is there a completely different way of doing it.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Otherwise, by going a bit into the direction of $x_j$, you would get larger values than at $x_0$ which is a contradiction

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch can you please explain it a bit more

Answer (score 1):

What is a maximum? It is a point $x_0\in \mathbf{R}^d$ so that for all $x$ "near" $x_0$, $f(x_0)\geqslant f(x)$. So if you take the directional derivative 
$$
D_h(f):= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+th)-f(x_0)}{t}
$$
for any unit vector $h$ (corresponding to any direction), $D_h(f)$ should be non-positive (since the function is decreasing in every direction). What are partials? They are just directional derivatives with respect to a coordinate vector. Let $(e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_d)$ be a basis of $\mathbf{R}^d$, then $D_{e_i}(f)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial e_i}$. So if you can show that $D_h(f)\leqslant 0$ for all unit vectors $h$, you will get your result.

Hint (for showing $D_h(f)\leqslant 0$): What will the sign of $f(x_0+th)-f(x_0)$ be for unit vectors $h$ and $t$ small?