# Derivative Function

Tags: real-analysis, mean-value-theorem

Given $f(x) \ge 0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$ and $c \in (a,b)$. If $f'(c)$ exist and $f(c) = 0$, proof $$f'(c) = 0.$$

**My Attempt:**

By using Mean Value Theorem:
$$f'(c) = \frac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{|b-a|} \ge 0.$$
I want to proof that $f(b) - f(a)=0$. So that we can conclude that $f'(c) = 0$. But I dont get the way. Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $F$? Also how exactly can you use mean value theorem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632947/42969

Comment: Assume $f(c)$ is nonzero (therefore positive or negative) and examine the difference quotient with points to the left or right of $c$ accordingly.

Comment: I think we can use the fact that the function has a minima at $c$, as $f(x)$ is mentioned to be non-negative…

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{#1}$: The Mean Value Theorem is not really helping here, instead considering that $f(x)\geq 0\forall x\in (a,b)$ and $c\in (a.b)$. Given that $f(c)=0$, $c$ must be a local minima of the function in $(a,b)$. Therefore, the slope of the tangent of $f(x)$ at $x=c$, that is $f'(c)$, must be equal to $0$.

$\textbf{#2}$:Visualizing a graph of any such function also helps, if $f(x)\geq 0$ in $(a,b)$ and $f(c)=0$ where $c\in (a,b)$, then the $x$-axis must be tangent to the function at $c$, making $f'(c)=0$.