# Let :(,)→ℝ be a differentiable function. Show that if ()=sup{()∣∈(,)} for some ∈(,) , then ′()=0 .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Here is what I have so far:

suppose f'(c) > 0

then lim (f(x) - f(c)) / (x - c) = f'(c) > 0

there exists some delta > 0 s.t. if abs(x-c) < delta then lim (f(x) - f(c)) / (x - c) > 0

take x = c + (delta/2). not sure how to complete the proof, hopefully this explains where I am headed

Comment: Hint: We have for all $x\in (a,b)$ that $f(c)-f(x)\geq 0$. Use this to show that for all $x\in (a,c)$ $$\frac{f(c)-f(x)}{c-x}\geq 0$$ and for all $x\in (c,b)$ $$\frac{f(c)-f(x)}{c-x}\leq 0.$$ Take limits and conclude.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that the derivative of an extremum is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632947/proof-that-the-derivative-of-an-extremum-is-0)

Answer (score 0):

This part is not precise enough:

> there exists some delta > 0 s.t. if abs(x-c) < delta then lim (f(x) - f(c)) / (x - c) > 0

This is how you would phrase this more precisely: For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ such that $|x-c| < \delta$, the following inequality holds:

$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right| < \epsilon
$$

After this, my hint would be, if you are doing a proof by contradiction where you assume $f'(c) > 0$ and then you show a contradiction, to show a contradiction here, you can take $\epsilon = f'(c)/2$. Then, you have:

$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right| < \frac{f'(c)}{2}
$$

which can be rephrased as:

$$
f'(c)-\frac{f'(c)}{2} < \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} < f'(c)+\frac{f'(c)}{2}
$$

If $f'(c)$ is positive, then $f'(c)-f'(c)/2=f'(c)/2$ is positive and thus the above inequality says $(f(x)-f(c))/(x-c)$ is positive. Then, how can you choose a value of $x$ which will give you a contradiction?